# Can I put more than 8 cameras on an 8 channel camera system?

Tags: wiring, security

I purchased a [Lorex 8 channel camera security system](http://m.costco.com/Lorex-8-Channel-IP-NVR-with-2TB-HDD,-8-1080p-Cameras-with-130-Night-Vision.product.100217003.html).  Everything works fine however, I would like to add additional cameras.

Can this be done using a POE switch?  The POE switch comes with 5 ports and [4 additional cameras](https://www.lorextechnology.com/HD-IP-camera/1080p-HD-IP-Security-Cameras-with-PoE-Switch-4-Pack/prod1040002.p).  When I look in the manual and on the site it says the device works for LNR Series camera systems.  The manual is very vague on this topic.  A local installer here says you can install but Lorex customer support says you cannot.

I'm not sure who is right in this situation.  If you read online the channel size indicates the number of cameras.  Mine is 8 channels which tells me 8 cameras...but if I use a POE switch can I not just add additional cameras?

Comment: Why does this question need more details?  LOL this was posted in 2015, got an answer and it reads very well. SMH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is no...I have the same setup as you. I tried adding 9th camera (wireless) It recognizes it but i can only add it if i remove one of the existing cameras so it looks like they put a limit on how many streams it can take and it could be because hardware limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Without any knowledge of this particular product, I'm going to say: maybe.

The limitation isn't how many Ethernet ports you can string together (answer: nearly infinite) but how many video streams the DVR can handle. It simply may not be able to physically handle more than 8 video streams. Also, the vendor may have put a limit in the software to not allow more than 8 video streams.

The only way to know for sure is to get a 9th camera and try it out for yourself.

Comment: Awesome response so far - The issue though is the back of the NVR only has room for 8 cameras, that would mean having to purchase a POE switch.  But the POE switches are expensive, hence my question...

Comment: @JonH you dont really need a PoE switch for one device.  PoE injectors can be had much cheaper, and add power to the cable from a regular switch.  Ensure they are compatible with your camera first.

Comment: Grant - im not sure I follow, if I've already got 8 cameras being used up in the NVR (back side of the NVR) how exactly am I going to get the 9th setup?  Plus the lorex brand never work with seperate switches, you always have to have some sort of Lorex POE switch to make it work.

Comment: @jonh plug in a normal network switch to one of the ports in NVR, then multiple cameras into switch.  Looks like those cameras use 802.3af for their PoE (based on some of the switches Lorex sells), injectors for that can be found for <$30 each.

Comment: Hmm the only issue is as longneck mentioned, can the nvr handle that much video...I would love to put in 4 more cameras but I would like someone who might have more experience that could answer that based on my initial post, the model I have, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. If you want such an arrangement, it's either you buy 16 channel NVR with eight ports, then you buy 8 port PoE switch. Now you populate your NVR with the cameras, then you add the additional camera to the PoE. Connect the PoE switch to the NVR. That's the surest way. If originally the NVR can pick 8 cameras, you cant exceed the 8 channel But if its 8 port NVR but supports 16 cameras, that arrangement can work.